# Swift property observers: why is didSet not called on an array property if the array is amended by appending a new array?

Tags: arrays, swift, didset, property-observer

I have a string array and I also wish to create a localised copy of this array (whilst keeping the original array intact).

There are a number of ways to do this, but I thought I might use a property observer to set the contents of the localised array, when the contents of the non-localised array are modified.

I created a test property observer as such:

```
// Array  to store the card theme names
private var cardThemeNames = [String]() {
    didSet {
        // debug print statement
        print( oldValue )
    }
}
```

Interestingly, if I amend the cardThemeNames array one element at a time, then the didSet method of the observer is called, as expected, i.e.:

```
cardThemeNames.append( "Random" )
```

However, if I modify the array by appending another array, then disSet is not called, i.e.:

```
cardThemeNames.append( contentsOf: someOtherArray )
```

or:

```
cardThemeNames += someOtherArray
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case and confirm if property observers generally only work when modifying one element of a collection?

Thanks.

Comment: didSet gets called for me in all situations you've listed

Comment: works for me too. show us the non-working scenario.